# Moving between views in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

ok so, im on on SwiftUI Xcode 11.3.1 trying to call a second view after login

the working design of the second view is on the file mainView.swift

after the login I'm calling my view like this

```
Button(action: {
                self.status =  dologin(username: self.username, password: self.password)
                if (self.status){
                    print ("log in succesfull")
                    mainMenu() // <-- return of "mainMenu" initializer is unused

                }
            })
```

I know you can call a. subview like `.sheet(isPresented)` but this won't work for me cause is a login screen.
thanks in advance.

Comment: You might find this helpful  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58104813/change-the-root-view-of-uihostingcontroller-in-swiftui/58105259#58105259

Answer (score 2):

You need to control views in other way in SwiftUI, you can't just `push` or `pop` view, like in UIKit. Apple proposes `NavigationView` and you can use something like `NavigationLink(destination: YourLoginView(), isActive: $someBindingVariable, label: Text(""))`, but I really don't like to play with `.navigationBarHidden(true)` and `.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)` and other staff. There are some options:

1. Use `.popover(isPresented: $needToLogin) { // login view }`. Either you can use `.sheet`. In this case user can move your "Login view" to bottom and use "Main view" as usual:

```swift
struct MovingViewsSwiftUI: View {

    @State private var needToLogin = true
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle() // your "Main view"
            .popover(isPresented: $needToLogin) {
                LoginView(needToLogin: self.$needToLogin) // will show you at the end
        }

    }

}
```

2. You can use `if...else` statements, for example:

```swift
//...
var body: some View {
    if needToLogin {
        return AnyView(LoginView)
    } else {
        return AnyView(MainView)
    }
    // something else in body
}
```

3. You can use `ZStack` and control views `.opacity` or `.offset`. It allows you to achieve interesting animations:

```swift
struct MovingViewsSwiftUI: View {

    @State private var needToLogin = true
    var body: some View {

        ZStack {
            LoginView(needToLogin: $needToLogin)
                .opacity(needToLogin ? 1 : 0)

            Rectangle()
                .opacity(needToLogin ? 0 : 1)

        }

    }

}
```

and here is the example of `LoginView`:

```swift
struct LoginView: View {

    @Binding var needToLogin: Bool
    @State private var email: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("enter email", text: $email)
            TextField("pass", text: $password)

            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    self.needToLogin = false
                }

            }) {
                Text("Log in!")
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add button in NaigationView like this.

```
 NavigationLink(destination: mainMenu()) {
                            Button(action: {

                            }) {
                              Text("Log in!")
                            }
                        }
```