# SwiftUI: How to change the root contentview during runtime

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am using Firebase to authenticate in my app. What I am trying to achieve is that when you authenticate, you are sent to the dashboard page of my app. I am new to swiftUI and I can't seem to work out a neat way of doing this. I also want it so that on subsequent loads of the app, if the user is still logged in then the app won't bother with showing the Authentication pages at all, it will just show the dashboard page.

When I worked in storyboards what I would do was set the Dashboard page to be the initial view controller and on viewDidLoad, I would check if I was logged in. if I was then I would Navigate(Modally) to the auth pages.

TLDR: is there a neat way to have navigate to the auth pages on load if you are not logged into your app?

I apologize if this seems like a simple question. I am still very new with swiftUI.

Comment: This answer has answered my question exactly, making use of combine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59538247/9882015

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to simply swap the `rootViewController` of your `UIWindow`. It's not really related to the SwiftUI - you do it in the same way as you would do it using UIKit (just using UIHostingController instead of UIViewController).

Snippet below is not the best way to do this but the simplest way for sure. In real production app, you should pass your UIWindow instead of using singleton and do not force unwrap.

```swift
// After the user has been authenticated
let yourSwiftUIView = Text("Hello World")
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: yourSwiftUIView)
```

With the same approach you can select what UIViewController or UIHostingController you want to open on the startup of your app (inside `AppDelegate`s `didFinishLaunching` for example)